# How to setup a throuput whereby we have mulitple different request in time interval using jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have the following scenario. So I have an OS process sample that will send a request to the console app and wait for the process to finish, I want to control the request to be line 6 Request in an hour.

So send 1 Request wait 10 min send another request wait 10 mins...at 20 min point after the first request send 2 requests (could have a wait time of 30 seconds) in between the request then at the 40 min mark have another request. I have been reading about precise throughput timers but I am not new to Jmeter so trying to get some help if possible.

1 request of 5k                   at : xx:00 min

2 requests ( 1 each of 2k, 5k ) at : xx:20 min  ~

1 request of 2k at : xx:40 min -

1hr no activity

repeat steps 1-4 a few ( 3 ) times

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to run requests with different throughput values within the bounds of a single Thread Group, the overall throughput would be the speed of the "slowest" request.

All JMeter timers like [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer), [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer) and [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) are trying to spread the load **evenly** during the throughput period.

So your load pattern can be implemented only using [Constant Timers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) or [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) samplers, whatever is more convenient to you.

Something like this:

[image]

You can use [Test Fragments](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment) and [Module Controllers](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421345-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller) to avoid copying and pasting the requests

Comment: This is perfect answer thank you dimitri

Comment: How do we do a test fragment in this case?